# Replace NULL value from list in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, forecastr

i have a `dataframe` with field as `list()`, but sometimes it have null values, i've tried `replace(is.null(.), 0)` in my query but nothing happened.

i want to :

- replace train with `list(date=exactly date in the rows, sales=0)`
- displaying train.sales

here is my dataframe :
https://pasteboard.co/IsclvYT.png

content inside dataframe :
https://pasteboard.co/IscmiwV.png

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

As the 'train' is a `list`, we can loop through the `list` and replace the `NULL` elements with `0`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate(train = map(train, ~ replace(.x, is.null(.x), 0)))
```

Based on the comments, the OP wanted to replace the `NULL` elements with the corresponding 'date' from 'test'

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(train = map2(train, test, ~ if(is.null(.x)) list(date = .y$date, sales = rep(0, length(.y$sales))) else .x))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- sapply(df1$train, is.null)
df1$train[i1] <- 0
```

Comment: thank you, it works.. but i wanna replace it with list(date=exactly date in the rows, sales=0) sorry im new in R

Comment: @hartono-  According to the question, you want to replace with 0, right?

Comment: @hartono-  Sorry, I am not following your comments about what the replacement would be

Comment: @hartono-  Did you meant the dates in 'test"  If it is of length n, then would be there be 'n' dates and also should the sales be 0 of length n?

Comment: @hartono-  I updatd the post.  Can you please check